# Finding the word immediately after a character with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to look for the word that is immediately after '%' in the following line:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:Feb 26 20:04:01.869 UTC: esd[361]: %PKT_INFRA-FM-3-FAULT_MAJOR : ALARM_MAJOR :SWITCH_LINK_ERR_E :DECLARE :0/RP0/CPU0/7:

LC/0/9/CPU0:Feb 26 20:00:25.560 UTC: npu_drvr[253]: %PLATFORM-OFA-6-INFO : NPU #1 Initialization Completed
```

To start, I used the following Python code, and it is working.

```
result = re.search(r"\%.* \: ", txt)
result.group()
```

And [here](https://regex101.com/r/hs0wec/1) is the result:

However, my reg ex fails in lines like this:

```
LC/0/9/CPU0:Feb 27 15:33:58.509 UTC: npu_drvr[253]: %FABRIC-NPU_DRVR-1-PACIFIC_ERROR : [5821] : [PACIFIC A0]: For asic 0 : A0 Errata: Observed RX CODE errors on link 120 , This is expected if you have A0 asic versions in the system and do triggers like OIR, reload etc.
```

Comment: If you mean it picks up too much on the .*, just use non greedy matching, "\%.*? \: " instead of "\%.* \: " (add ? after *).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repetitions (`*` and `+`) in regular expressions default to "greedy" mode: they try to match the longest piece of text. In the failure case you provided, there are additional colons (`:`) in the message after the word to match, so the greedy star `*` matched them all.

You can change the behavior to "lazy" (or "non-greedy") by adding a question mark (`?`) after the repetition, changing it to:

```py
result = re.search(r"\%.*? \: ", txt)
```

Check out the results [here](https://regex101.com/r/hs0wec/2). For more information, consider reading [this article](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy).

Comment: Neither `\ ` is necessary: `%` and `:` do not have special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a percent sign followed by one or more non-spaces:

```
re.search("%\S+", s)
#<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(52, 84), match='%FABRIC-NPU_DRVR-1-PACIFIC_ERROR'>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
re.search(r'%([^\s]+)', s).group(1)
```

output (tested against the line for which your regex fails):

```
FABRIC-NPU_DRVR-1-PACIFIC_ERROR
```

or you can use:

```
 re.search(r'%(\S+)', s).group(1) # \S is the same with [^\s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import re

x="LC/0/9/CPU0:Feb 27 15:33:58.509 UTC: npu_drvr[253]: %FABRIC-NPU_DRVR-1-PACIFIC_ERROR : [5821] : [PACIFIC A0]: For asic 0 : A0 Errata: Observed RX CODE errors on link 120 , This is expected if you have A0 asic versions in the system and do triggers like OIR, reload etc."

res=re.findall(r"(?<=%)[^\s]+", x)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

['FABRIC-NPU_DRVR-1-PACIFIC_ERROR']
```

`(?<=%)[^\s]+` - first brackets will be a match only if `%` is preceding the second brackets, without actually returning `%`. Next brackets are a match only for the word - meaning string of 1, or more characters, that aren't white space.